# Can I construct in Perl a network type message that has odd byte length

Tags: perl

```
$str = "0xa"; #my hex number
$m = pack("n",hex("$str")); --> the output is 000a 
$m = pack("c",hex("$str")); --> the output is 0a
```

I need the result to be only `a`. The bottom line is that, with pack, I can send on a socket, messages that have odd length (like `A675`). If I try to send `A675B` then with pack I will have `A6750B`

Answer (score 4):

`A675` is two bytes. `A675B` is two *and a half* bytes. Sockets don't support sending anything smaller than a byte. You could send a flag that tells the receiver to ignore one nybble of the message, but that's about it.

Comment: Yes you are right. What I want to do is send like 5 hexs from a client to a server using a socket connection